# Why doesn't MIPS have a Store Immediate instruction just like Load Immediate instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set, immediate-operand, instruction-encoding

MIPS has a Load Immediate (`LI`) pseudo instruction to load a 32-bit immediate value into a register. But it does not have Store Immediate (`SI`) instruction to store a 32-bit immediate value to Memory. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: mips does not have a load immediate instruction, there is lui and ori which are real instructions li is a pseudo instruction, think of it as a macro.

Comment: none of these (lui, nor ori) operate on memory, so having an si "just like" li would also mean not operating on memory.

Comment: An instruction containing both an immediate value and a memory address would be much longer than the instruction format allows.

Comment: Pseudo-instructions are a feature of the assembler, not the processor. MIPS CPUs don't have a LI instruction, it's MIPS assemblers that have a LI pseudo-instruction. That means there's nothing stopping you from creating your own assembler, or modifying an existing one, to create your own SI pseudo-instruction. You might even be able to do it using the macro features of an existing assembler. However you need to make your pseudo-instruction generate real MIPS instructions that a MIPS CPU can execute. So you need to figure out what real MIPS instructions your SI instruction would use.

Answer (score 4):

load immediate is from immediate to register, store immediate would be register to...immediate...that doesnt make sense.  you want to store to memory you load a register with data a register with an address and do a store.  it is (supposedly) a load and store architecture, you do everything (memory-wise) through registers, not directly.

Comment: My question was, suppose Store Immediate(SI) is an instruction that stores a 32-bit immediate value to memory why is it not implemented in MIPS?

Comment: Why would it be?  why doesnt mips have a memory to memory move or add, etc? Why doesnt it have a HACF instruction?   It certainly doesnt fit with the mips design thats for sure (store immediate to memory without a register being involved as the source) but you would have to go ask the designers what they were thinking that day.